# Openpyxl - Add key,value pairs from two different Excel rows in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying in here to save the cell values from a specific row as keys and cell values from another row as values, all together in a dictionary.

Using the code below, I managed to save first row(green marked) as keys in the dictionary.

But what I'm struggling with, is to save the second row(yellow marked) as values in the dictionary.

```
dictData = {}

#get row 2 
for row1 in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=2, min_col=3, max_col=ws1.max_column):
    for cell1 in row1:
        #get row 5
        for row2 in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=5, max_row=row_data, min_col=5, max_col=ws1.max_column):
            for cell2 in row2:
                    dictData[cell1.value] = cell2.value
```

[image: Table]

While running the above mentioned code, it stores for each value in the dictionary, only the last data from the row("20"-data from China).

```
{'Total': 20, 'USA': 20, 'Canada': 20, 'UK': 20, 'France': 20, 'Germany': 20, 'India': 20, 'Japan': 20, 'Singapore': 20, 'China': 20}
```

Does anyone have any idea/feedback on how to solve this? For sure I'm missing something in the 'for loop'.

Thank you! :)

Comment: If u don’t mind, cud u share a link to an excerpt of ur excel file so we cud test it out and post a possible solution

Comment: Sure thing :) Down below you can find the WeTransfer link. 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/bcaf35babee25fee8ad71b511303d06b20200410153806/8b143c

If you want another transfer portal, please tell me and I'll upload it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just had a look at ur shared data; since you are interested in just two rows (rows 2 and 5), you can read them individually,zip the data, and dict the zipped data. the relevant data starts from column 3, so I've included that as well:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
filename = 'Project_yxz.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active

#read in the data
row2 = ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=2, min_col=3, values_only=True)
row5 = ws.iter_rows(min_row=5, max_row=5, min_col=3, values_only=True)

#zip and dict
res = dict(zip(*row2,*row5))

res

{'Total': 720,
 'USA': 72,
 'Canada': 34,
 'UK': 54,
 'France': 46,
 'Germany': 38,
 'India': 120,
 'Japan': 101,
 'Singapore': 47,
 'China': 20}
```

Lemme know if this is what u have in mind. further reading from openpyxl docs [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#values-only)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks Sammy! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try not to nest the iterations. Read row 2 on its own.

Then iterate from 5 to something.

If you need the header for something then store it in a different directory e.g. with column name as key. Then access it later.

You create the following dictionary from the first row:

```
headers = {1:'Total', 2:'USA'}
```

Later when you iterate through the rest of the rows and columns you access it to get the
name. You know the column index. Maybe you need to fix the offset or something.

```
some_other_dictionary = {headers[column_index]: 'some_value'}
```

Another possibility is to use something like [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) which should do the hard work for you.

Comment: Sadly, I need to store first row as key and second row as value. Can't use pandas for this :(
Can you please explain in more detail on what to do regarding the nested for loops?
I planned on nesting the loops, in order to save both keys & values in a single go.

Answer (score 1):

This does not call for a nested loop. For each outer value (dict key) you need only one inner value (dict value). Thus, the inner loop should be off size 1, which is no loop at all.

However, you must of course align your inne values with the outer ones. In most classical programming languages this would be achieved looping over an index used to address both items, i.e.

```
# Naive way
dictData = {}
for i in range(2, len(ws1[3])):
    dictData[ws1[3][i].value] = ws1[5][i].value
```

This, however, is not very pythonic, as Python allows looping directly over the values. But looping over the outer values only, still requires an index to the inner values. This can be found using `enumerate` in the loop, to get both the value and its index:

```
# Enumerate inner value (not very nice)
dictData = {}
for i, key in enumerate(ws1[3][2:], 2):
    dictData[key.value] = ws1[5][i].value
```

Not much is gained by this, though, as we still need an index. We really want to be able to get both the dict key and the dict value from the loop directly. And, lo and behold, Python has a solution ready for us, namely using `zip` which allows us to align two series in one `for` loop:

```
# Using zip, nicer and more pythonic
dictData = {}
for key, value in zip(ws1[3][2:], ws1[5][2:]):
    dictData[key.value] = value.value
```

Now we are getting somewhere. This is more like it, but we can go even further, using so-called dict comprehension, which allows us to create and assign the dict in one go:

```
# dict comprehension
dictData = {key.value: value.value for key, value in zip(ws1[3][2:], ws1[5][2:])}
```

Either of the last two is OK, I would say, even though I prefer the dict comprehension as I find it quite easy to read, but your milage may vary.

Also, as a final note, to get the code to feel even more pythonic, replace the camelCased `dictData` with the more PEP8 compliant form `dict_data`. But that is of course only correct if that style is used for all variables in your project. It is more important to be consistent.

Comment: Wow! Your answer and explanation is brilliant! 
Too bad I can't accept more than one answer :( 
Thank you so much Johan!